# sencha touch create tabs from store data

Tags: extjs, tabs, touch, store

I am new to Senscha Touch and I have been struggling with this for hours.

I am trying to create an application where the main page has 1-3 tabs where title and content(html5) depends on json data.

My model has two fields: "title" and "text". 
My store has dummy data for 2 tabs:

```
Ext.define('***', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    config: {
        model: '***',
        xtype: 'informationTabs',
        data: [
            {
                title: 'Museum',
                text: 'Random html5'
            },
            {
                title: 'Museum_2',
                text: 'Random html5_2'
            },
            {
                title: 'Museum_3',
                text: 'Random html5_2'
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

To show it as a list i have the following code:

```
Ext.define('***', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    xtype: 'informationsTabs',
    config: {
        title: 'InformationTabs',
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'list',
                store: 'InformationTabs',
                itemTpl: '{title}, {text}'
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

How do I get that to instead of making a list with two items, create two tabs with their title and text inside?

So in this case i should have two tabs. 
Tab 1: Title = "title_1", content = "random_html5"
Tab 2: Title = "title_2", content = "random_html5_2"

**Update:**
With the following code (thanks kevhender!) it "works", except i get an extra "[object Object]" as the first tab. This option is also the only one with blue background when you click that tab.

Also this.callParent(); gets "Unresolved function or method".

> ```
> Ext.define('***', {
> extend: 'Ext.TabPanel',
> xtype: 'informationsTabs',
> config: {
>     title: 'informationsTabs',
>
>     items: [
>         {
>             xtype: 'tabbar',
>             store: 'InformationTabs',
>             title: '',
>             html: ['']
>         }
>     ]
> },
> initialize: function() {
>     var items = [];
>     Ext.getStore('InformationTabs').each(function(rec) {
>         items.push({
>             title: rec.get('title'),
>             html: rec.get('text')
>         });
>     });
>     this.setItems(items);
>     this.callParent();
> } });
> ```

screenshot: http://oi41.tinypic.com/2gsn53p.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Since the store is dynamic, you won't be able to do the full definition in your static `config` block.  You could put the tab creation into the `initialize` method, something like this:

```
Ext.define('***', {
    extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
    xtype: 'informationsTabs',
    config: {
        title: 'InformationTabs',
        layout: 'fit',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'list',
                store: 'InformationTabs',
                itemTpl: '{title}, {text}'
            }
        ]
    },
    initialize: function() {
        var items = [];
        Ext.getStore('InformationTabs').each(function(rec) {
            items.push({
                title: rec.get('title'),
                html: rec.get('text')
            });
        });
        this.setItems(items);
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```